# Call to a member function latest() on string in laravel

Tags: laravel

What is this error.

> Call to a member function latest() on string

Controller

```
public function search()
{
    $keyword = request('search');
    $articles = Article::search($keyword)->latest()->get();
    return $articles;
}
```

Model

```
public function scopeSearch($query , $keyword)
    {
        $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%".$keyword."%");
        return $keyword;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't return a string from the [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes). So, change it to:

```
public function scopeSearch($query , $keyword)
{
    return $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
}
```